# Changing an image to embedded data

Tags: image, flex4, embedded-resource

I know how to embed an image, but I want to change an image to any of the embedded images on request (a function call).

```
[Bindable]
public var icoEstado:Class;

[Embed(source="src/assets/etapa.n.png")]
[Bindable]
private var estadoN:Class;

[Embed(source="src/assets/etapa.ok.png")]
[Bindable]
private var estadoOk:Class;

[Embed(source="src/assets/etapa.x.png")]
[Bindable]
private var estadoX:Class;

public function estado(i:String):void
{
 switch(i)
 {
  default:
  case 'x':
   icoEstado = estadoX;
  return;
  case 'n':
   icoEstado = estadoN;
  return;
  case 'k':
   icoEstado = estadoOk;
  return;
 }
}
```

and then...

```
<s:BitmapImage id="ico" source="{icoEstado}"/>
```

This isn't working... any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: What is it doing?  If you just put source="/src/assets/etapa.x.png" or something, do you see that image?  (side note: your private variables don't need to be Bindable)

Comment: If I put ico.source="../src/assets/etapa.x.png" it doesn't work... it only worked putting source="{estadoX}", or source="{estadoOk}" directly on the BitmapImage tag. (but then again, I would want to change it dinamically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I've found is to use the `mx:Image` component instead.